# Where is git add file located

Tags: git

I am working on a linux ubuntu server.  I accidentally ran git add in a very large directory and used up all of the storage space on the system.

I need to remove a file that I created using the `git add` command.  Is there a command to remove this file? Alternatively, where are these files stored so that i can locate and remove it manually.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `git reset <filepath>` for unstage file

git reset HEAD < file> unstages any modifications made to the file since the last commit

alternatively can try caution it will change the file content from last commit

```
To unstage one file :
$ git checkout <path-to-file>

Remember to replace <path-to-file> with the actual file name.

To unstage all files:
$ git checkout -- .
```

useful comment by – Stephen Newell

> @Paul - You probably need to do git gc --prune=all. That'll delete any
>   objects git add created, but it has some risks (check the docs).

Comment: When i try `git reset .` or `git reset HEAD .` i get the message `fatal: Could not write new index file.`

Comment: did u adding file path

Comment: Yes it appears to fail when i include the filepath.

Comment: Deleting a file using `rm` to create a small amount of space and then running `git reset HEAD .` allowed the command to run.

Comment: @Paul - You probably need to do `git gc --prune=all`.  That'll delete any objects `git add` created, but it has some risks (check the docs).

Comment: I think it was because i accidentally used up 100% of the disk space on the server and needed to clear a tiny amount in order to initiate writing a new index file.

Comment: @StephenNewell - Thanks for your suggestion.  running `git gc --prune=all` appears to have worked and increased the amount of available disk space.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid accidental repack by "git gc", you could also run "git prune" which only removes the new objects. Probably it would also require dropping current index. So, overall:

```
rm .git/index
git prune --expire now
# to restore the index
git reset
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Note: this is basically [max630's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845027/1256452), with some additions and annotations, plus the long explanation below.

1. Free up enough space to get some work done, or remove the index entirely if you're OK with that.
2. Delete or replace bad index entries if you did not remove the index entirely in step 1.
3. Run `git prune --expire now`.
4. If you removed the index in step 1, run `git reset` to rebuild it.

## Long

For anyone who comes across this later, here's an answer that attempts to be thorough.  While the usual description is that `git add` copies a file into the index—which is true at a high level—in your particular case, where you have run out of disk space on the file system, that's not sufficient.  Also, we might like to use something like the BFG to clean up the mistake here, but if we are truly out of space, anything that actually creates *new* files is going to have problems.

First, let's note that "the index" is really a file named `.git/index`,<sup>1</sup> but what it contains is not complete copies of other files.  Instead, it has one small "entry" per file,<sup>2</sup> giving the file's name, some important cache data, and a *blob hash ID*.  The index starts out holding one entry for every file in the checked-out commit.  When you run `git add path`, you either replace an existing entry or add a new entry, depending on whether *`path`* was in the index before.

This means that just removing `.git/index`, or fixing up entries that your `git add` added or overwrote, is not going to fix the problem.  It is, however, an important *first step*.  The *second* step is to remove the *blob itself*, which is a bit trickier.  The problem here is that the blob is stored as an object in the Git objects database, which is where Git is storing *all* of your repository data: every file within every commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Modern Git has what it calls a "split index", where the index contents are spread across two separate files, but the principles are the same.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, each file has up to 4 entries, using "staging slot" numbers, but `git add` uses only slot zero.  Slots 1, 2, and 3 are used only when merging.  Adding a file erases the higher stage slots, so after `git add` you are guaranteed to use only stage-slot zero.

---

#### Our main goal is to get rid of these unwanted blob objects

The direct answer to your sub-question:

> where are these files stored so that i can locate and remove it manually

is that each blob object is stored (currently!) as a *loose object*, `.git/objects/ab/cdef0123...` or some such.  We want to be rid of these objects, but they are mixed in with many objects that we *don't* want deleted, so it's unwise to just remove objects without care.  Moreover, even if we delete just the correct blobs, if we do it without cleaning up the *index*, our Git will become unhappy.

If there are only one or two such files, we can do this all relatively manually.  If there are many such files, we'll want to automate the job.  Let's start with the most-manual method, and then see how to automate it later.

## Manually fixing two simple mistakes

Let's deliberately make two different mistakes here.  To do so we need a repository with some commit checked out, and some very big file:

```
$ git checkout something     # check out some commit or branch
$ cp /external/hugefile existingfile    # copy very big file
$ cp /external/hugefile newfile         # into our work-tree
```

Now we're ready to make our two mistakes:

```
$ git add existingfile       # mistake type #1
$ git add newfile            # mistake type #2
```

With mistake type #1, we overwrite a small file with a huge one.  This small file was already in the index and work-tree because it was in the commit; we just overwrote the work-tree file and then told Git to copy that file into the index, which it did.  With mistake type #2, we created a new huge file.  It was not in the work-tree before, and it was not in the index before, and now it is in the work-tree *and* in the index.

#### Getting the blob hash ID

We can get the big files' hash or hashes—with the procedure outlined above, there will be only *one* hash—using `git ls-files --stage`:

```
$ git ls-files --stage existingfile newfile
100644 <hash> 0    existingfile
100644 <hash> 0    newfile
```

The hash ID will depend on the blob content, but will look like, e.g., `1b4624c876dae8f38f7c9e13f82d11b6ead39c9b`.  This tells us where Git has stored the actual object.  We'll need that *after* we fix the index.

#### Fixing the index

Before we remove the unwanted blobs, we must first remove the *references* to it.  In other words, we want our index to no longer tell Git that Git should be looking for that blob, or those blobs.

There is a circular problem here though: we are, presumably, *totally out of space*.  Git cannot update the index without creating a new one.  Git's process for updating `.git/index` is to create a new, empty `.git/index.lock` file, to prevent other Git commands from running, then to write out a *new* (updated) index into the lock file.  Once the lock file is safely written to permanent storage, Git *renames* `.git/index.lock` to make it replace `.git/index`, so that the unlock and the switching to the new index happen simultaneously.  This means we need a little bit of space.  Fortunately we can get a lot of space: we just made two huge files that we don't want.  Let's just clobber one or both of them, e.g.:

```
$ cp /dev/null existingfile
```

(assuming a Unix/Linux-ish command line).  You can remove the file entirely but if so you'll get a few minor complaints from subsequent Git commands.

The next step for recovering from mistake type #1 is to switch back to the correct file in both index and work-tree:

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- existingfile
```

This has Git extract the correct file from the current commit into the index, then extract that index file into the work-tree.  The step for recovering from mistake type #2 is to remove the huge file entirely:

```
$ git rm -- newfile
```

which removes it from both the index and the work-tree, or:

```
$ git rm --cached newfile
```

which removes it from the index (only), leaving it in the work-tree (assuming you have some reason to retain it, in which case you had best not have clobbered it earlier to get the space back).

#### Manually removing the blob object

If the hash ID above was `1b4624c876dae8f38f7c9e13f82d11b6ead39c9b`, we can now remove the object with a simple file delete:

```
$ rm .git/objects/1b/4624c876dae8f38f7c9e13f82d11b6ead39c9b
```

This file name is simply `.git/objects/` followed by the *first two* characters of the hash ID followed by `/` followed by the *rest* of the hash ID.  The actual file will be read-only, so your remove command is likely to ask if you are sure about this.

Repeat this until you have removed all added giant-blobs, and you're done.

## Automating it

In your particular case, you added many big files, all within some subdirectory.  So you will want to just:

```
$ git rm -r --cached subdir/*
```

or the equivalent.  As before, you will first have to do *something* to free up some space.  Technically, it's OK to delete one of the big objects like we did manually above (using `git ls-files --stage` to find a hash ID), provided you're *sure* that this hash ID does not appear elsewhere in the repository.  The `git rm -r --cached` won't ever bother to look for the object.

#### Using `git prune`

Now that all of these are gone from the index, we want to ask Git to *prune unreferenced objects*.  The *prune* verb here has a very specialized meaning, but let's talk first about *unreferenced objects*.

**A Git object is *referenced* if it is findable by its hash ID.**  That's all there is to it, but that's actually a rather complicated statement: how, exactly, does Git do this *finding?*  I won't go into the full details here, but let's just note that a *reference name*, like a branch or tag name, contains a hash ID, usually the ID of a commit.  The commit contains the hash ID of other commits and of a *tree* object, and the *tree* object has names and hash IDs for *blob* objects.  This means Git can use the name to find the commit to find the tree to find the blob.  When Git does so, that blob is *referenced*.  Meanwhile, so were the commit and the tree: Git had to *use* them to *find* the blob.

The *index* also acts as blob references!  Every index entry—each file name with its staging slot and blob hash ID—counts as a reference to that blob.  So if a file is in some commit and Git can find that commit, that file—more precisely, the blob object holding the file's content—is *referenced*.  Likewise, every blob object currently in the index is referenced.  Some objects are referenced many times: for instance, if your `README.md` file is the same in a thousand commits, it has at least a thousand references.  **Git does not care how many references an object has, as long as it has at least *one*.**

What `git prune` does is find *loose* objects<sup>3</sup>—commits, annotated tags, trees, and blobs—that have *zero* references, and *remove* them.  That's pretty much all it does, but that's also rather important, because that lets Git generate objects whenever it wants to.  If Git ends up not *using* the object after all, well, it will just go away on its own.  So `git add` can just create tons of loose objects.  If they get committed, they live forever; if not, they'll be pruned away eventually.

There is one hitch, though: `git gc` sometimes runs `git prune` automatically for you, all invisibly in the background, while you are doing other work.  To make sure that `git prune` does not destroy an object that's only *temporarily* unreferenced, `git prune` has a default *grace period* of 14 days, during which an unreferenced loose object just sticks around anyway.  That means that every Git command has two weeks to finish up and make sure that objects are referenced.

Here, we want to specifically defeat the default two-week grace period, so we use `git prune --expire now`.

---

<sup>3</sup>The adjective *loose* here mean *an object that has not been packed*.  In other words, the opposite of *loose* is not *tight*, but rather *packed*.  *Packing* is a way to further compress Git objects.  The packing code only packs up *referenced* objects, so as to avoid interfering with the pruning code, in a rather complicated dance that `git gc` orchestrates.  We're not using the full `git gc` here as we only want to work with the loose objects that `git add` creates.

---

#### Removing and rebuilding the index

If we *remove* the index entirely as our first step, that automatically means that there are no blob references from the index.  Git itself is OK with the index being missing: this is a normal state in a bare repository.  The index has multiple purposes, but one of its key ones is to cache data about the work-tree while you do your work, and a bare repository has no work-tree (by definition).

So, removing the index itself also removes all of the index's references to all the blobs in the current commit.  This has the side effect of "un-adding" everything: all files are now scheduled to be removed, as compared with the current commit, if you were to make a new commit.  In other words, a *missing* index is the same as an *empty* index.

We can leave everything this way for the duration of the `git prune` operation, then *re-generate* the index from the `HEAD` commit, using `git reset --mixed HEAD`.  Since `--mixed` is the default and `HEAD` is the default, `git reset`, with no options at all, does the job.

Hence, if it is OK to "un-add" *everything*, we end up with the three step sequence of commands at the top: remove index, prune, restore index.